# Android slow AlphabetIndexer on cursoradapter

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, fastscroll, sectionindexer

Noticeably slow/Jittery AlphabetIndexer on a CursorAdapter

My listview scrolls smoothly but scrolling up and down when holding the alphabetindexer scrollbar is a bit jittery

I am already using a ViewHolder

I have set the following on my list

```
mListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

I have setup my alphabetindexer as follows

```
public class FeedFragmentAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

            AlphabetIndexer mAlphabetIndexer;

            public FeedFragmentAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
                super(context, cursor, flags);
                cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                this.context = context;
            }

    public void setIndexer(Cursor cursor){

        mAlphabetIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(cursor,
                cursor.getColumnIndex("name_format"),
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTSUVWXYZ");
        mAlphabetIndexer.setCursor(cursor);//Sets a new cursor as the data set and resets the cache of indices.

    }
            /**
             * Performs a binary search or cache lookup to find the first row that matches a given section's starting letter.
             */
            @Override
            public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex)
            {
                return mAlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(sectionIndex);
            }

            /**
             * Returns the section index for a given position in the list by querying the item and comparing it with all items
             * in the section array.
             */
            @Override
            public int getSectionForPosition(int position)
            {
                return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
            }

            /**
             * Returns the section array constructed from the alphabet provided in the constructor.
             */
            @Override
            public Object[] getSections()
            {
                return mAlphabetIndexer.getSections();
            }
```

The below was not suitable as i am already using a viewholder
[Android Laggy AlphabetIndexer in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315673/android-laggy-alphabetindexer-in-listview)

Comment: How many rows cursor contains? What is the size of the row(does it contains blob)? I had same issue when cursor change window(native data under the cursor)

Comment: @Selvin, I do not have many rows, around 100 records, no blobs, do not know how to check the size of the row but each row has around 15 columns with very little data in each column, just short strings or integers. The query for the cursor is made up of around five joins but i assume that the query is not rerunning while i am scrolling. Each cursor record is checked via newview method to determine which one of five list row views items the record  should bind. The view is simple user contact view with 2 small images from the drawable folder and the contact name.

Comment: hmmm does cursor is ordered by the column used in indexer?

Comment: no the column used in indexer is not the order by column, the results are ordered by multiple columns. The column used by indexer   is a formatted version of the name column to convert null columns to empty string. some of the rows near top of the list are not in alphabetical name order but majority are in alphabetical order